# Batch files compare numbers

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I have to write a script that check if there is enough space in the drive.
I wrote the following:

```
@echo off
set gbsize = 1,073,741,824
Set gbsize=%gbsize:,=%
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir c:\') do (
    set /a bytesfree=%%a
)
set bytesfree=%bytesfree:,=%
endlocal && set bytesfree=%bytesfree%

If %gbsize% gtr %bytesfree% echo hi
```

but when the script thrown error: 
**Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17),
hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021).**

what did I miss? can anyone help?
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your immediate problem is attempting to use SET /A when there are commas in your value.

You also need to remove the spaces before and after = when you define gbsize.

I don't understand why you have endlocal without a setlocal

I believe this is what you were looking for. It will echo "hi" if there is less then 1GB free space.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set gbsize=1,073,741,824
Set gbsize=%gbsize:,=%
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir c:\') do set bytesfree=%%a
set bytesfree=%bytesfree:,=%
If %gbsize% gtr %bytesfree% echo hi
```

Another, more direct, (and possibly more accurate?) way to get the free space

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%S in ('wmic volume get DriveLetter^, FreeSpace^|find "C:"') do set bytesfree=%%S
```

Comment: first, thanks for your help!! in addtion, I want to write script that find the volume with the max free space, and copy file to him, can you please help me to do it?

Comment: @RRR - I answered this on your [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9099138/1012053)