# Checking Remaining Harddisk Space in a DOS Batch Script. IF Condition not working

Tags: windows-7, if-statement, batch-file

I'd like to have a notification that informs me when my hard disk space is getting low.  I'm running Windows 7 Professional and I think a quick batch file could handle this.  I'll schedule it to run once a day.  This is what I have so far:

This finds the remaining disk space using the "dir" command and the "find" command.  It stores the value in Var1.  (This works for me)

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir ^| find "free"') do SET WinVer=%%i 
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=]-" %%A IN ("%WinVer%" ) DO ( 
SET Var1=%%A 
)
```

This pulls the number from the the result and removes the commas.  The result will look like "111222333444" without the quotes: (This works for me)

```
set Var1=%Var1:~10,15%
set Var1=%Var1:,=%
```

This checks if the value in Var1 is less than 100 GB (my hypothetical disk space floor).  If so, it creates a file called "lowSpace.txt" that I'll see at some point.  (This doesn't work for me)

```
if %Var1% leq 100000000000 dir > lowSpace.txt
```

This "if" statement is causing me problems.  My free disk space is about 150 GB (or 150000000000), so the if condition should fail and the "dir > lowSpace.txt" should not be running, but it does anyway.

- If I increase the constant in the "if" statement from 100000000000 to 500000000000, the file "lowSpace.txt" is created as I expect.
- Or, if I increase the constant again from 100000000000 to 500000000000 and change the condition from "leq" to "geq", the file "lowSpace.txt" is created when I would expect it to not be created.

Am I comparing my numbers wrong?  Or is something wrong with my "if" statement?  The code seems to consider 150 GB to be both greater than and less than 100 GB.

---

Here is my full script:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir ^| find "free"') do SET WinVer=%%i 
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=]-" %%A IN ("%WinVer%" ) DO ( 
SET Var1=%%A 
) 
set Var1=%Var1:~10,15%
set Var1=%Var1:,=%

if %Var1% leq 100000000000 dir > lowSpace.txt
@echo on
@echo %Var1%
```

Note that 100 GB isn't my real hard disk space floor.  I'm just using that number to test my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked and answered this very question at [Windows batch file IF failure - How can 30000000000000 equal 40000000000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116365/windows-batch-file-if-failure-how-can-30000000000000-equal-40000000000). Your problem is Windows batch cannot handle numbers greater than ~2 GB. If treats any number greater than 2 GB as equal to 2 GB. 
I posted a simple work around that prefixes the numbers with zeros and forces a string comparison instead of a numeric comparison.

Note, you can also use WMIC to get the free space of any given drive:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%S in ('wmic volume get DriveLetter^, FreeSpace ^| findstr "^C:"') do set freeSpace=%%S
```

Comment: I didn't realize that my number could be too big.  I took another route and divided my numbers by 1000 and my code worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`wmic` command is sometimes unavailable.

So, in a singleline :

```
for /F "tokens=8" %%? in ('fsutil volume diskfree C:') do set FREE_SPACE=%%?
```

Result is in variable `%FREE_SPACE%` in `bytes`.

Comment: Nice snippet. However on Win10 it only works in an elevated command shell (Run as Administrator).