# Batch script checking file size methods?

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code in one of my scripts, but it doesn't seem to be reliable. It seems that if the file is actually less than 1 it might fail. Or at least it did for someone.  Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to do this ?

In short, check that file.txt is > 0 :

```
for /f %%i in ("file.txt") do set size=%%~zi
    rem added THIS:  if not defined size set size=0
if %size% gtr 0 (
    type file.txt >> %FNAME%
) else (
    echo     No Data Found On System >>  %FNAME%
)
```

EDIT: Issue was created with code I changed upstream. Basically made it so file.txt potentially was never created. I renamed file.txt to something like foobar.txt in the code to replicate the issue. Putting "if not defined size set size=0" seemed to resolve this problem.

Comment: Are you sure that is the exact code that failed? I don't see how it can fail unless the code is included in a larger parenthesized block of code.

Comment: There is no need to set size. You can put your IF statement in your DO clause, and substitute `%%~zi` for `%size%`. Then you don't have to worry about being within a parenthesized code block.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is. I put markers in the code when running on this other person's system and it crapped out here. It is not inside of another "(" of code but inside of a function. We changed his system to have 1 entry in file.txt and it worked hence for > 0. It has me concerned because I use this in other places of the code as well. THought I had it all tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is the file must not exist, in which case `%%~zi` expands to nothing (not 0). That is easily fixed by explicitly setting size to 0 afterward if size is not defined.

```
for /f %%i in ("file.txt") do set "size=%%~zi"
if not defined size set size=0
if %size% gtr 0 (
    type file.txt >> %FNAME%
) else (
    echo     No Data Found On System >>  %FNAME%
)
```

Comment: What if size GTR 2^31 ?  Compare will FAIL.

Comment: NEQ instead of GTR should cure that. (if greater 2^31, the value will be negative)

Comment: @captcha - No, it will actually work OK if size GEQ 2^31 because of a quirk with how IF works. Numbers greater than (2^31 - 1) are treated by IF as equal to (2^31 - 1). See [Windows batch file IF failure - How can 30000000000000 equal 40000000000?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9116365/1012053) for more info.

Comment: @Stephan - No, IF will not treat overflow numbers as negative. See my prior comment to captcha.

Comment: This was the issue, basically some code changes up stream potentially causes file.txt to never be created in some cases.  Thanks for you help. REALLY appreciated. :-)

Comment: If that's the case you need a line at the top like this: if not exist file.txt echo bugger off & goto :EOF