# Batch script - IF not returning properly result

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a batch script and i need to compare 2 variables which are integer numbers but i can't get it to work properly.

The comparison that i need to do is something like that:

```
if (201308281436 GTR 201308292309) (@ECHO true) Else (@ECHO false)
```

As far as i know (i don't know much about dos programming but i can do basic things), it should return "True" but it returns always "false".

I made some checks on cmd and this are the results:

```
if (1 GTR 2) (@ECHO true) Else (@ECHO false)
false

if (1 GTR 0) (@ECHO true) Else (@ECHO false)
false
```

the code that im using on bat script:

```
if (%filemodifieddate% GTR %filelastbackupdate%) (@ECHO true) Else (@ECHO false)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the parantheses!

```
if 1 gtr 0 (echo true) else echo false
```

You are comparing `(1` with `0)` instead of comparing `1` with `0`

***EDIT*** - *The workaround given below only works if both numbers have the same number of digits. See [Windows batch file IF failure - How can 30000000000000 equal 40000000000?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9116365/1012053) for method to compare large integers with varying number of digits.*

EDIT:
found a nice workaround: compare strings, not numbers (by adding a `a` in front of the numbers.

Experiment with this:

```
@echo off
if a%1 lss a%2 echo one
if a%2 lss a%1 echo two
```

(put it in a batchfile (t.bat) and execute with two parameters:

```
> t 1 3
one
> t 3 1
two
> t 54135143513513153 5613535314535543
one
> t 5613535314535543 54135143513513153
two
> t 5613535314535543 5413514351351315
two
> t 5413514351351315 5613535314535543
one
>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked but i also found that the original numbers that i want to compare are too big and it make IF fail.

Comment: @Mykos - This comparison will only work properly if the numbers have the same number of digits. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9116365/1012053 for the proper way to compare large integers.

Comment: @dbenham see run 3 and 4. It looks like it would run fine with different number of digits. I tried it with the numbers from your link. Maybe it works because my addition of an `a`.

Comment: @dbenham The numbers that i want to compare are dates like yyyymmddhhmm, so the numbers will always have the same size

Comment: Runs 3 and 4 are giving the wrong answer! The first number in run 3 has 17 digits, the second 16 digits. Yet you report that the first number is smaller! Runs 5 and 6 work because the numbers have the same number of digits

Comment: @Mykos - Yep, that simplifies matters greatly.

Comment: @dbenham I just did some more testing. You are right - output is confusing and not reliable with different number of digits.

Comment: if you make the strings equal, you can compare huge numbers with approx. 8191 digits and maybe more. Simply add leading zeros to the shorter string.