# Sorting files by size except executive file

Tags: cmd

I need sort files in current directory by size and move it to corresponding folder. The difficulty is not to touch the `.bat` file. And I cant do this.
For example this line will be move `.bat` file and script will be stoped.

```
forfiles /p %CD% /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c if @fsize gtr 100 move @file %~dp0/200"
```

Comment: The difficulty I have is understanding your question. What does corresponding folder mean?

Comment: Also, do you want to preserve the current location of all `.bat` files, or just the currently executing one?

Comment: @dbenham For example folders named `100`, `200`, `300`(named by size of files which need to sort)

Comment: @dbenham Just the currently executing one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place a lock on the current batch file

```
< "%~f0" (
    forfiles ....
)
```

As the batch file is redirected for input, it is locked, and can not be moved or deleted

EDITED - As dbenham remarks, error handling must be considered, so lets exclude the current batch file from processing

```
forfiles /p "%cd%" /m * /c "cmd /c if @fsize gtr 100 if /i not @path==\"%~f0\" move @path \"%cd%\200\" "
```

If filesize > 100, if full path of file being processed is not equal to the full path of the current batch file, then move the file

Not sure if the target should be a subdirectory of the current folder of a subdirectory of the folder where the batch file is located (if not the same), so, first option used.

EDIT 2 - If for some reason the size condition changes and folders fall under the check, they can be excluded adding an aditional if condition

```
forfiles /p "%cd%" /m * /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE if @fsize gtr 100 if /i not @path==\"%~f0\" move @path \"%cd%\200\" "
```

Comment: +1, That is a clever way to do it. However, either an unwanted error message is generated, or if you redirect errors to nul then all errors are lost. Ideally it should only attempt to move the file if it is not itself so that error messages are preserved.

Comment: Also, extra code should be added to prevent attempt to move folders.

Comment: @dbenham, well, for me fsize returns 0 in the case of folders, so, the size text excludes them, but anyway, test for directory included

Comment: Good point. But I'm assuming the classification logic will become more complex, and a file can also have size=0.

Answer (score 2):

I try to avoid FORFILES because it is quite slow. I generally only use it when I need date computations.

A simple FOR /R loop is both much faster, and also simpler I think. It will automatically only iterate files. It defaults to the current directory, as you are currently using.

`%%~fF` yields the full path to the currently file iteration, `%%~zF` the file size, and `%~f0` yields the full path to the currently executing batch script.

The following should replicate the logic of the code in your question, except that it also prevents movement of the currently executing batch script. I also redirected output to nul to hide the `1 file(s) moved.` message. This solution should be much faster than FORFILES.

```
for /r %%F in (*) do if "%%~fF" neq "%~f0" do (
  if %%~zF gtr 100 move "%%F" "%~dp0\200" >nul
)
```

You may or may not want to add the `/Y` option to the MOVE command.

If you must differentiate between large files that are larger than 2 gigabytes, then you cannot directly compare the filesize because batch numeric conditions are limited to 2147483647. See [Windows batch file IF failure - How can 30000000000000 equal 40000000000?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9116365/1012053) for more information, including a strategy on how to deal with large file sizes.

Comment: `IF` limits on values being checked only affect the right part of the test. As far as it keeps under 2147483648 it will work independly of the size of the file

Comment: @MCND - No, both sides are affected the same. However, it only becomes an issue if there needs to be differentiation among files that are larger than 2GB. Any number greater than 2GB will be treated as 2GB when doing a numeric IF comparison. Perhaps this is what you meant by your comment, but it wasn't clear.

Comment: Sorry, poorly expressed. I was just thinking in execution errors.