# when is batch IF compare-op done numerically

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, windows-7, comparison-operators

I have looked but cannot find a specification of precisely when a batch file IF comparison using a numeric compare-op (eg gtr) is done numerically instead of treating its arguments as strings.

I found this question [Windows batch file IF failure - How can 30000000000000 equal 40000000000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116365/windows-batch-file-if-failure-how-can-30000000000000-equal-40000000000/9116378) but its explanation -- If you have any non digit characters, then IF does a string comparison -- isn't complete.  For example:

```
@echo off& setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if "123" gtr "99" echo greater
if 099 gtr 10 echo greater
if "+1000" gtr "0x99" echo greater
if 12-1 gtr 3 echo greater
if +1000 gtr 0x99 echo greater
```

Only the last IF above is done numerically and echoes greater... yet **neither** side of its compare-op is comprised entirely of digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both arguments can be converted to a numeric, then the comparison is performed numerically, unless either side is quoted.

Hence, since +1000 and 0x99 are both numeric according to the parsing rules (see `set /?` then the comparison is performed numerically (a string starting `0x` is interpreted as a hex and otherwise if it starts `0`, then octal)