# Batch - Cleaner way to find largest given variable?

Tags: batch-file

The following code works for my problem but as you can see it is heavily protracted. So i was wondering if there was a more efficient way to find the largest of 6 given variables.

**Code**

```
    @echo off
    Set /a picture0 = 4
    Set /a picture1 = 10
    Set /a picture2 = 9
    Set /a picture3 = 6
    Set /a picture4 = 71
    Set /a picture5 = 6
    Set /a picture6 = 5

    Call :TestPicture0
    Call :TestPicture1
    Call :TestPicture2
    Call :TestPicture3
    Call :TestPicture4
    Call :TestPicture5
    Call :TestPicture6
    @pause
    GoTo :EOF
```

So I have the six variables I want to use right, and I call each of them separately because they are rather long.

```
  :TestPicture0

    Set /a Test01 = %picture0% - %picture0%
    Set /a Result01 = 0
    Set /a Test02 = %picture0% - %picture2%
    Set /a Result02 = 0
    Set /a Test03 = %picture0% - %picture3%
    Set /a Result03 = 0
    Set /a Test04 = %picture0% - %picture4%
    Set /a Result04 = 0
    Set /a Test05 = %picture0% - %picture5%
    Set /a Result05 = 0
    Set /a Test06 = %picture0% - %picture6%
    Set /a Result06 = 0

    if %Test01% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result01 = 1)else (Set /a Result01 = 0)
    if %Test02% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result02 = 1)else (Set /a Result02 = 0)
    if %Test03% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result03 = 1)else (Set /a Result03 = 0)
    if %Test04% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result04 = 1)else (Set /a Result04 = 0)
    if %Test05% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result05 = 1)else (Set /a Result05 = 0)
    if %Test06% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result06 = 1)else (Set /a Result06 = 0)

    Set /a Picture0Final = %Result06% + %Result05% + %Result04% + %Result03% + %Result02% + %Result01%

    If %Picture0Final% EQU 6 (Echo Picture Zero) Else (Echo no)
    GoTo :EOF




    :TestPicture1
    Set /a Test10 = %picture1% - %picture0%
    Set /a Result10 = 0
    Set /a Test12 = %picture1% - %picture2%
    Set /a Result12 = 0
    Set /a Test13 = %picture1% - %picture3%
    Set /a Result13 = 0
    Set /a Test14 = %picture1% - %picture4%
    Set /a Result14 = 0
    Set /a Test15 = %picture1% - %picture5%
    Set /a Result15 = 0
    Set /a Test16 = %picture1% - %picture6%
    Set /a Result16 = 0

    if %Test10% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result10 = 1)else (Set /a Result10 = 0)
    if %Test12% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result12 = 1)else (Set /a Result12 = 0)
    if %Test13% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result13 = 1)else (Set /a Result13 = 0)
    if %Test14% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result14 = 1)else (Set /a Result14 = 0)
    if %Test15% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result15 = 1)else (Set /a Result15 = 0)
    if %Test16% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result16 = 1)else (Set /a Result16 = 0)

    Set /a Picture1Final = %Result16% + %Result15% + %Result14% + %Result13% + %Result12% + %Result10%

    If %Picture1Final% EQU 6 (Echo Picture one) Else (Echo no)
    GoTo :EOF





    :TestPicture2
    Set /a Test20 = %picture2% - %picture0%
    Set /a Result20 = 0
    Set /a Test21 = %picture2% - %picture1%
    Set /a Result21 = 0
    Set /a Test23 = %picture2% - %picture3%
    Set /a Result23 = 0
    Set /a Test24 = %picture2% - %picture4%
    Set /a Result24 = 0
    Set /a Test25 = %picture2% - %picture5%
    Set /a Result25 = 0
    Set /a Test26 = %picture2% - %picture6%
    Set /a Result26 = 0

    if %Test20% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result20 = 1)else (Set /a Result20 = 0)
    if %Test21% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result21 = 1)else (Set /a Result21 = 0)
    if %Test23% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result23 = 1)else (Set /a Result23 = 0)
    if %Test24% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result24 = 1)else (Set /a Result24 = 0)
    if %Test25% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result25 = 1)else (Set /a Result25 = 0)
    if %Test26% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result26 = 1)else (Set /a Result26 = 0)

    Set /a Picture2Final = %Result26% + %Result25% + %Result24% + %Result23% + %Result21% + %Result20%

    If %Picture2Final% EQU 6 (Echo Picture Two) Else (Echo no)
    GoTo :EOF





    :TestPicture3
    Set /a Test30 = %picture3% - %picture0%
    Set /a Result30 = 0
    Set /a Test31 = %picture3% - %picture1%
    Set /a Result11 = 0
    Set /a Test32 = %picture3% - %picture2%
    Set /a Result32 = 0
    Set /a Test34 = %picture3% - %picture4%
    Set /a Result34 = 0
    Set /a Test35 = %picture3% - %picture5%
    Set /a Result35 = 0
    Set /a Test36 = %picture3% - %picture6%
    Set /a Result36 = 0

    if %Test30% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result30 = 1)else (Set /a Result30 = 0)
    if %Test31% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result31 = 1)else (Set /a Result31 = 0)
    if %Test32% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result32 = 1)else (Set /a Result32 = 0)
    if %Test34% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result34 = 1)else (Set /a Result34 = 0)
    if %Test35% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result35 = 1)else (Set /a Result35 = 0)
    if %Test36% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result36 = 1)else (Set /a Result36 = 0)

    Set /a Picture3Final = %Result36% + %Result35% + %Result34% + %Result32% + %Result31% + %Result30%

    If %Picture3Final% EQU 6 (Echo Picture Three) Else (Echo no)
    GoTo :EOF





    :TestPicture4

    Set /a Test40 = %picture4% - %picture0%
    Set /a Result40 = 0
    Set /a Test42 = %picture4% - %picture2%
    Set /a Result42 = 0
    Set /a Test43 = %picture4% - %picture3%
    Set /a Result43 = 0
    Set /a Test41 = %picture4% - %picture1%
    Set /a Result41 = 0
    Set /a Test45 = %picture4% - %picture5%
    Set /a Result45 = 0
    Set /a Test46 = %picture4% - %picture6%
    Set /a Result46 = 0

    if %Test40% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result40 = 1)else (Set /a Result40 = 0)
    if %Test42% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result42 = 1)else (Set /a Result42 = 0)
    if %Test43% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result43 = 1)else (Set /a Result43 = 0)
    if %Test41% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result41 = 1)else (Set /a Result41 = 0)
    if %Test45% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result45 = 1)else (Set /a Result45 = 0)
    if %Test46% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result46 = 1)else (Set /a Result46 = 0)

    Set /a Picture4Final = %Result46% + %Result45% + %Result41% + %Result43% + %Result42% + %Result40%

    If %Picture4Final% GEQ 6 (Echo Picture Four) Else (Echo no)

    GoTo :EOF





    :TestPicture5
    Set /a Test50 = %picture5% - %picture0%
    Set /a Result50 = 0
    Set /a Test51 = %picture5% - %picture1%
    Set /a Result51 = 0
    Set /a Test52 = %picture5% - %picture2%
    Set /a Result52 = 0
    Set /a Test53 = %picture5% - %picture3%
    Set /a Result53 = 0
    Set /a Test54 = %picture5% - %picture5%
    Set /a Result54 = 0
    Set /a Test56 = %picture5% - %picture6%
    Set /a Result56 = 0

    if %Test50% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result50 = 1)else (Set /a Result50 = 0)
    if %Test51% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result51 = 1)else (Set /a Result51 = 0)
    if %Test52% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result52 = 1)else (Set /a Result52 = 0)
    if %Test53% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result53 = 1)else (Set /a Result53 = 0)
    if %Test54% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result54 = 1)else (Set /a Result54 = 0)
    if %Test56% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result56 = 1)else (Set /a Result56 = 0)

    Set /a Picture5Final = %Result56% + %Result54% + %Result53% + %Result52% + %Result51% + %Result50%

    If %Picture5Final% EQU 6 (Echo Picture Five) Else (Echo no)
    GoTo :EOF





    :TestPicture6
    Set /a Test60 = %picture6% - %picture0%
    Set /a Result60 = 0
    Set /a Test61 = %picture6% - %picture1%
    Set /a Result61 = 0
    Set /a Test62 = %picture6% - %picture2%
    Set /a Result62 = 0
    Set /a Test63 = %picture6% - %picture3%
    Set /a Result63 = 0
    Set /a Test64 = %picture6% - %picture6%
    Set /a Result64 = 0
    Set /a Test65 = %picture6% - %picture6%
    Set /a Result65 = 0

    if %Test60% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result60 = 1)else (Set /a Result60 = 0)
    if %Test61% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result61 = 1)else (Set /a Result61 = 0)
    if %Test62% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result62 = 1)else (Set /a Result62 = 0)
    if %Test63% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result63 = 1)else (Set /a Result63 = 0)
    if %Test64% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result64 = 1)else (Set /a Result64 = 0)
    if %Test65% GEQ 0 (Set /a Result65 = 1)else (Set /a Result65 = 0)

    Set /a Picture6Final = %Result65% + %Result64% + %Result63% + %Result62% + %Result61% + %Result60%

    If %Picture6Final% EQU 6 (Echo Picture Six) Else (Echo no)
    GoTo :EOF
```

If yall know a way to make this better please let me know :D----<-<
*Edit: fixed some 0's to ones ... literally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you asked how to

> find the largest of 6 given variables

There is no need to minus each and compare the result to 0. It isn't even neccessary to compare the variables.

```
@echo off
====SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions


set/a"picture0=4,picture1=10,picture2=9,picture3=6,picture4=71,picture5=6,picture6=5,MAX=0"
FOR /L %%# in (0 1 6) do if !picture%%#! GTR !max! set/a"max=!picture%%#!,max_var=%%#"
echo MAX is picture%max_var%=%max%
```

---

Limitations:

- If `%picture3% == %picture4% == 6`, `%max%` will be `picture3`.
- Works for 32-bits integers only. See [Windows batch file IF failure - How can 30000000000000 equal 40000000000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116365/windows-batch-file-if-failure-how-can-30000000000000-equal-40000000000)
- In this case, because the variables are in a "list", I used a `FOR /L` loop . But in case it's not, use `FOR`.

Comment: Alternatively, a for /F loop over the set command for arrays of various / changing size. `For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims==" %%A in ('Set picture') Do If "!Max!" == "" (Set "Max=%%B" & Set "MaxV=%%A") Else If %%B GTR !Max! (Set "Max=%%B" & Set "MaxV=%%A")`

Comment: @T3RR0R post that as an answer :o, i thought of using `SET`, but i don't wanna take credit for that

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @HackingAddict1337's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62112095/12343998):

A `For /F` loop using the Set command in conjunction with the Array variable prefix can be used to retrieve the highest value withought needing to know / reference the size of the Array:

```bat
Setlocal ENABLEdelayedexpansion
For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims==" %%A in ('Set picture') Do If "!Max!" == "" (Set "Max=%%B" & Set "MaxV=%%A") Else If %%B GTR !Max! (Set "Max=%%B" & Set "MaxV=%%A")
```

Comment: In order for this to achieve its intended aim, you would need to include a method for enabling delayed expansion, _(otherwise `!Max!` will simply be a string and never be empty)_!

Comment: That should  be obvious  enough given the use of ! expansion

Comment: How should that be obvious to the OP, T3RR0R? You don't know their level of understanding, their question or code didn't imply they understand delayed expansion or how to use it? And the only code under this question which does try to use it, is what your code is supposed to be an alternative to, and I've got to be honest, as I've never seen a command named `====SETLOCAL`, I doubt that's going to be very helpful.